# MikTeX update from basic install (2.9.6850) fails with fatal error

Tags: miktex, miktex-update

Windows 7 Pro (64bit), account with admin rights: Installing "for all" basic MiKTeX 2.9.6850 works okay, all settings as per default. However, when I try to update it using MiKTeX Console (Admin), I get the following error:

> INFO  main - starting: MiKTeX Console 2.9.6821 (MiKTeX 2.9.6840 64-bit)
>   ERROR mainwindow - Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\win\DllProc.cpp:62: Windows API error 127: The specified procedure could not be found.
>   (dllName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin/x64\MiKTeX209-core.dll")

Correspondingly, any subsequent attempt to compile using latex/pdflatex produces a pop-up with `Entry Not Found Error`, saying

> The procedure entry point
>   ?FatalErroe@Application@App@MiKTeX@@QEAAXPEBDZZ could not be located in the dymamic link library MiKTeX209-app.dll

I also tried to refresh manually databases (file names/font maps) but it did not work. The only option is then to deinstall and insall basic again, skipping update... Please could anyone help me how to overcome this?

Just wanted to add that I've been using MiKTeX successfully over many years, but have started to have such issues recently after the move to MiKTeX Concole. Also, these issues seem to be present only when the update indicates "core" files (`miktex-...`) -- just LaTeX packages seem to be ok. In earlier days, when all worked fine, it was necessary to update twice (first "core", then "rest"), but this is no longer the case. Still, could this somehow be related?...

Comment: The question is wrong here, add an issue to the miktex issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. Where is "miktex issue tracker"?

Comment: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I've found the answer to my question in this thread there:
https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/187

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems that this issue is known from this thread: 
https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/187
The workaround suggested there is to repair the MiKTeX installation by running:

```
initexmf --admin --update-fndb
initexmf --admin --mklinks --force
```

This worked for me!

Comment: Only works for shared setup.  Can't install shared setup on Windows 10 b/c there's another bug.  I don't remember MiKTeX being such rubbish.

Comment: Thank you for this. I wish I could give you +1000. Thank you, thank you!