# Help me to install TeX4ht on windows

Tags: tex4ht

I am trying to ask new ways of converting tex -> HTML here:
[Latex to not PDF on Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/544163/latex-to-not-pdf-on-windows)

but it seems nothing new and I need to edit ini files manually. Ok.

I am trying to follow this manual:
https://tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn-mswin.html

but with a correct, I dont want TeX4ht location on my disk C:.

So, I create tex4ht folder elsewhere, download tex4ht.zip and stuck on step c.
Where I can find "tfm files of TeX and LaTeX"? I tryed to investigate MiKTeX folders, trying to use Win search, but I cant find them. Also, I found tex4ht folder in there. Does it mean tex4ht is a part of MiKTeX?

Comment: tex4ht is part of the standard miktex and texlive tex distributions you should not have to install it "by hand"

Comment: as David said, TeX4ht is part of TeX distributions, so you don't need anything. The section in documentation you refer to is obsolete. See [Make4ht documentation](https://www.kodymirus.cz/make4ht/make4ht-doc.html) on how to run the basic conversion.

Comment: I am trying to use mike4ht in cmd console: "make4ht filename.tex", but got error:"miktex windows api error 127 the specified procedure could not be found" I find MikTex console and launch Upgrading, but got else error:"Windows API error 127: The specified procedure could not be found." I follow this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/460831/miktex-update-from-basic-install-2-9-6850-fails-with-fatal-error and launch Upgrade again, but it cant find any upgrades this time. Using "make4ht filename.tex" gave mame error again.

Comment: I don't use Windows and Miktex, so I cannot tell what is wrong here. it seems like some specific Miktex error regarding installation and updating of the packages.

Comment: Ok, I use portableversion and launch make4ht from cmd console. It says: make4ht-lib:fatal error. Command htlatex returned exit code 1

Comment: `TeX4ht` came with some default mapping and scripts, so think to alter the default setup is a risky one...